# House keeping in remote server

Tags: shell, sftp

I want to know how to house keep(delete) the files which there in remote server by connecting using SFTP based retention period for n customers and each customer will have different directory.

Note: We don't have privileges to write script and run in remote server. We need to write script in our server to connect remote by using SFTP protocol.

Thanks,
Dasaradha

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux `sftp` can run in batch mode and delete files on remote site: http://linux.die.net/man/1/sftp.

Comment: Thanks PeterM,we are using batch mode only, but for n customers is it possible to have one batch file?

Comment: Don't get this. You can create the batch on the fly with customer data and run sftp multiple times.